# Optical optimization by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm

I want to simulate some cylindrical lamps in MATLAB and try to homogenize the intensity of them on a uneven surface.

To make the problem simpler, I assume that the length of each lamp is 100 cm and the surface is even (100 x 25 cm).

In the first step to make the problem simpler again, I tried to simulate just one lamp to minimize the variance of intensity on some points of surface. For this purpose I wrote a Fitness function which is actually the intensity formula:

[image: Intensity formula]

- r = distance of a point which you want to find the intensity there (in meter)
- l = width of surface which I put 1 (m)
- P = the output power of each lamp that I'm going to use 15W ones

Also the fitness function code is :

```
function [ intensity ] = simple_fitness(x)

global Pout;      % Pout = 15 Watts
r = (( x(1)^2 + x(2)^2 )^(1/2))*((10)^(-2));
intensity = (( Pout / (6 * r) )*( x(2)/r ));

end
```

The constraints are necessary too. As I said the goal is minimizing the variance of  intensity on some points and I have some unknown problems here.

The constraint function code is:

```
function [c, ceq] = simple_constraints(x)
global Pout;             %Pout
intensity = zeros(1,26);
avgint = 0;
minus = 0;
for i=0:25
     r = (( (x(1)-i)^2 + x(2)^2 )^(1/2))*((10)^(-2));
     intensity(i) = (( Pout / (6 * r) )*( x(2)/r ));
end

avgint = mean(intensity);
for j=1:25
     minus = minus + ( intensity(i) - avgint )^(2);   
end

c = -(sqrt(minus)/avgint) + 0.12 ; %actually it's not the variance formula 
ceq = [];

end
```

Some Hints : The `x(1)` and `x(2)` are the location of lamp in space: vertical axis = `x(2)` horizontal axis = `x(1)`

On the line 6 I put a loop which counts from 0 to 25. This line shows the points which I want to compute intensity there. On the line 7, I wrote that code to attain the distance ( It's just high school geometry :) )

I said I want to minimize the variance but here I made a new formula to attain my goal, it is a little bit different from variance formula. In variance formula we should divide the squared deviation of each element from its mean value by number of elements but here I divided them by mean value again (there are some reasons for that which they are out paper :/ )

At the end the main function code is :

```
objectiveFunction = @simple_fitness;
nvars = 2;
global Pout;
Pout = 15;
UB = [25 40];   %% 0<x<25 (cm) / 20<y<40 (cm) lamp
LB = [0 20];
constraintFuntion = @simple_constraints;
rng default
[x ,fval] = ga(objectiveFunction, nvars,[],[],[],[],LB, UB, constraintFuntion)
```

Then I got these errors :

[image: Errors]

What is the problem exactly ???

Comment: Please don't post images of your error messages, copy-paste them here instead.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error message saying that "subscript indices must be real **positive** integers" in this line:

> ```
> intensity(i) = ...
> ```

...which is embedded in a loop `for i=0:25`, so `i` starts at `0`, which is not a positive integer.

Indexing in MATLAB starts at 1.